# How to split a string at every n characters or to nearest previous space

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to insert a newline character at every 15 characters including spaces.

I'm currently using the regex below which is working to some extent but it is taking me the nearest space after the word and I want the nearest previous space. Any ideas?

```
const split = str.replace(/([\s\S]{15}[^ ]*)/g, '$1\n');
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Try `replace(/[\s\S]{1,15}(?!\S)/g, '$&\n')`

Comment: That works perfectly thanks! Would you mind just running me through the last group and the replace term at the end?

Comment: Also can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as done?

Comment: Your explanation was great thanks. no need for more clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
s.replace(/[\s\S]{1,15}(?!\S)/g, '$&\n')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OyIQDP/1)

**Details**

- `[\s\S]{1,15}` - any 1 to 15 chars, as many as possible (that is, all 15 are grabbed at once and then backtracking occurs to find...)
- `(?!\S)` - a position not immediately followed with a non-whitespace (so a whitespace or end of string).

Note that there is no need to wrap the whole pattern with `(...)` since you may refer to the whole match with a `$&` placeholder from the replacement pattern.

Comment: Doesn't work on, say, 20 characters long word without any spaces.

Comment: @ux.engineer Of course it does not work for you, because you have different requirements.

Comment: Wiktor...right, the defined requirements in this question's description are somewhat different - however the question's current title "How to split a string at every n characters or to nearest previous space" is exactly what I'm looking for. Care to update the title so I can make a new question with that title?