# Regex / JavaScript: Split string to separate lines by max characters per line with looking n chars backwards for a possible whitespace?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

This is similar question to [How to split a string at every n characters or to nearest previous space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801855/how-to-split-a-string-at-every-n-characters-or-to-nearest-previous-space), however, on the contrary to what I was expecting based on the title, that solution does not work if there is just one long word without any whitespace.

So I need a Regex which **splits a string to separate lines** (multiple times if needed) **by max characters per line**, and **looking backwards *n* characters for a possible whitespace** (break there if found, otherwise at max length)?

**Edit 1:** For example, with max line length 30 characters with 15 characters backwards whitespace lookup:

> Loremipsumissimplydummytextofthe printing and typesetting industry.

That sentence's first word has a length of 32 characters. So the output should be:

```
Loremipsumissimplydummytextoft  # Line has length of 30 char
he printing and typesetting     # Cut before the word at otherwise 30 char
industry.
```

So the first word should be force-cut after 30th character, as there was no whitespace.

The remaining string has a length of 28 (or 29 with the dash) before word 'industry', so at the place of 30th character there's a word, so the solution looks up for the previous whitespace within 15 characters range. That line is broken before 'industry' word.

**Edit 2:** Second example of text:

> Loremipsumissimplydummytextofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumis simply dummytext ofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumissimplydummytextofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumis simply dummytext ofthe printing and typesetting industry.

Should output:

```sh
Loremipsumissimplydummytextoft
he printing and typesetting
industry. Loremipsumis simply
dummytext ofthe printing and
typesetting industry.
Loremipsumissimplydummytextoft
he printing and typesetting
industry. Loremipsumis simply
dummytext ofthe printing and
typesetting industry.
```

**Use case for this regex is to format a long string into readable text with max line length enforced and lines starting with a character and not a whitespace.**

**Optional requirement:** When after initial posting I added that example in Edit 1, I also added an optional requirement for adding a dash '-' character at start of the next line, if a word was cut at max line length. I'm removing that from the example now and adding it as a separate optional requirement here.

So an optional requirement: If a line is broken mid-word at max-length and not at a whitespace, then a dash should be appended at the end of that line (and not at start of the next line, as I had originally described).

```
Loremipsumissimplydummytextoft-  # Line length 30+1 char with an appended a dash
he printing and typesetting     # Cut before the word at otherwise 30 char
industry.
```

Comment: Do you mean you need something like `[\s\S]{15,}?(?!\S)`? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Wiktor, not quite because that Regex doesn't enforce max-length of a line.

Comment: I'll add examples to the question.

Comment: Try `s.replace(/\S{30}|[\s\S]{1,30}(?!\S)/g, '$&\n')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/taFUxu/3))

Comment: Or, `s.replace(/(\S{30})|\s*([\s\S]{0,30})(?!\S)/g, '$1$2\n')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/taFUxu/2))

Comment: Second new demo is better as it takes out empty space on the third line's start. When [adding more lines of text](https://regex101.com/r/HUw8CC/1), it does seem still to include space on the start of 6th line?

Comment: Then, `\s*(?:(\S{30})|([\s\S]{1,30})(?!\S))`?

Comment: Now it's working nicely! Would it be too complex to add appending of a dash character at the end of the line that is broken, if broken at max-length without whitespace? (I'll update my question to clarify that optional requirement, as I also realized now that the dash should be included in the line that is broken and not at the start of the next line...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```js
var s = "Loremipsumissimplydummytextofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumis simply dummytext ofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumissimplydummytextofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumis simply dummytext ofthe printing and typesetting industry.";
var regex = /\s*(?:(\S{30})|([\s\S]{1,30})(?!\S))/g;
console.log(
  s.replace(regex, function($0,$1,$2) { return $1 ? $1 + "-\n" : $2 + "\n"; } )
)
```

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars.
- `(?:` - start of the non-capturing group:

  - `(\S{30})` - Group 1 (referred to with the `$1` variable in the callback method): thirty (`n`) non-whitespace chars
  - `|` - or
  - `([\s\S]{1,30})(?!\S))` - Group 2 (referred to with the `$2` variable in the callback method): any one to thirty (`n`)  chars, as many as possible, but not immediately followed with a non-whitespace char.

The `function($0,$1,$2) { return $1 ? $1 + "-\n" : $2 + "\n"; }` part means that if Group 1 matched (that is, we matched a very long word that is cut into two parts), we replace the match with Group 1 value + hyphen and a newline. Else, if Group 2 matches, we replace with Group 2 value + a newline.

**ES6+ compliant code snippet**:

```js
const text = "Loremipsumissimplydummytextofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumis simply dummytext ofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumissimplydummytextofthe printing and typesetting industry. Loremipsumis simply dummytext ofthe printing and typesetting industry.";
const lineMaxLen = 30;
const wsLookup = 15; // Look backwards n characters for a whitespace
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\s*(?:(\S{${lineMaxLen}})|([\s\S]{${lineMaxLen - wsLookup},${lineMaxLen}})(?!\S))`, 'g');
console.log(
  text.replace(regex, (_, x, y) => x ? `${x}-\n` : `${y}\n`)
);
```

Comment: @ux.engineer If you use `String.raw`, you do not need to double the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Final answer:

(\S[\s\S]{1,30}$|\S[\s\S]{1,29}(?:\s+)|\S{30})

evolution:

1. ([\s\S]{1,15}(?!\S)|\S{15,})

you just have to modify the answer in the link by an 'or' statement that adds your additional requirement: |\S{15,}

2. responding to your edits, here is my modified regex:
   ([\s\S]{1,15}(?!\S)|\S{15})

you can replace the 15s with 30 or the character cutoff of your choice

3. adjusting for your further clarifications:
   (\S[\s\S]{1,14}(?:\s*)|\S{15})

Now the string has to start with a none-whitespace and it matches but does not capture additional white space after the first 15 characters. Again you need to change the 15 and the 14 to the lengths you want.

4. (\S[\s\S]{1,30}$|\S[\s\S]{1,29}(?:\s+)|\S{30})
   Adding another condition in the multiple 'or' statement at the beginning which captures the end of the string if it ends in a none-whitespace character. If it ended in a whitespace character, the second part of the 'or' statement captures it.

Comment: That other question's requirements were different and the poster accepted an answer that does not enforce max-length of the line if the line does not include any whitespace. Here a demonstration of your proposed Regex: https://regex101.com/r/7Vem4D/1

Comment: That link shows that also your proposed regex is having the first line's length as 32, not cutting off the 32 characters long first word?

Comment: You edited your question and added more requirements. No wonder my answer no longer works!

Comment: That 'dash after cut word' requirement is optional. Max line length was always a requirement...I added only one example.

Comment: you only need to take the last comma out and it should work. i edited to show you. let me know

Comment: This is also a pretty decent solution now. However, it is still adding an empty space at start of the sixth line. Sorry for not elaborating in requirements on how these spaces before and after line breaks should be handled! But the usage case here is for breaking lines into readable text.

Comment: can you edit your question with a bunch of examples of before and after strings so i know what you exactly need. I don't even know what you mean by the 6th line.

Comment: Sorry I added additional lines of text on the example link on that another comments discussion. Am updating my example soon now. Link here: https://regex101.com/r/HUw8CC/1

Comment: I think i have your solution. Please check the updated answer and let me know.

Comment: There is something wrong with this revision, see here: https://regex101.com/r/GoImvy/1

Comment: @ux.engineer, i am not sure why you have {15,29} in there. it should be {1,29} I updated the solution to include another case. It works fully with your example.

Comment: I also tried with {1,12} but still it was outputting all rows in the same length. Anyhow, your [4th version](https://regex101.com/r/BJjVyu/1) works nicely! Wiktor also got to a working solution about an hour ago in the other comments thread, but he has not posted that as an answer, so I'm unsure which one of you got the accepted answer.

Comment: This does not match strings containing only one character.