# split string based on character limit and a period

Tags: javascript

I want to split a string based on 30 character limit and the catch here is it should get broken on a period(`.`) or a comma(`,`) or a space( ). i.e., the string length of 30 or a delimiter whichever comes first. I tried with the match using regex, this splits well, but not with a delimiter.

For example, Here is my sample code.

```js
let x='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Excepteur cuptat non proident, consectetur adipiscing elite detailo';

let splitString = x.match(/.{1,30}/g);

console.log(splitString);
```

Here the output I get is

```
[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ex",
  "cepteur cuptat non proident, c",
  "onsectetur adipiscing elite de",
  "tailo"
]
```

But I want this to happen using a comma or period or a space as a delimiter. Expected output is

```
[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
  "Excepteur cuptat non proident,",
  "consectetur adipiscing elite",
  "detailo"
]
```

Comment: did you try `/[^.,]{1,30}/` ? well actually if you include the space also: `/[^.,\s]{1,30}/` it will obviously break at every word

Comment: Would this post be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801855/how-to-split-a-string-at-every-n-characters-or-to-nearest-previous-space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let x='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Excepteur cuptat non proident, consectetur adipiscing elite detailo';

let splitString = x.match(/.{1,30}[\.\s,]/g).map(item => item.trim());
const remaining = x.replace(splitString.join(' '), '');
splitString = [...splitString, remaining.trim()]

console.log(splitString);
```

**Edit**:

I removed the trailing spaces in the substrings. Don't know if it's necessary but there is the exact wanted result now.

Answer (score 4):

You could match against this regex:

```
[^\s].{1,29}((?=\s|$)|(?<=[.,]))
```

which looks for a non-space character (`[^\s]`), and then up to 29 other characters (`.{1,29}`) which either:

1. are followed by a space or end-of-line `(?=\s|$)`; or
2. end with a comma or full-stop `(?<=[.,])`

```js
let x='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Excepteur cuptat non proident, consectetur adipiscing elite detailo';

let splitString = x.match(/[^\s].{1,29}((?=\s|$)|(?<=[.,]))/g);

console.log(splitString);
```